# Navigation menu should move left if it has child sub-menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, navigation

I am working on creating a navigation menu with four depth level's , I am displaying 3 depth levels at a time and when user enters into depth level-4, the 1st depth level should move left and display only 2nd , 3rd ,4th depth levels.

But the problem which  I am facing here is, on clicking of menu item in depthlevel-3(which doesn't have children) also the menu is moving left.

i.e.,Click on Menu-item1 > Menu-item1.2 > Menu-item1.2.2> Menu-item1.2.2.1
 here menu-item 1.2.2.1 doesn't have children but also menu is moving left

So in particular ,How i can move my menu left if it has child sub-menu only?

here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('.menu-item').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.dropdown',this).slideToggle(300);
    $('.col ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().find(".dropdown").hide();     
  });
  
  /*sub-col-1.2*/
  $('.col ul li').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().find("li").removeClass('active');
     //$('.sub-col li').removeClass('active');
    //$(this).children().find(".sub-sub-sub-col").hide();
    
  });
  
  /*sub-sub-col*/
  $('.col ul li ul').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
  

   $('.sub-sub-col > ul > li').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
      if (clicks) {
        $('.dropdown').animate({
             'left' : '0px'
        })   
      }
      else {
        $('.dropdown').animate({
             'left' : '-510px'
        })
      }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});


  
  
  /*sub-sub-sub-col*/
   $('.col ul ul li ul').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
 
});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Mada', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/*Container
===============*/

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #00A0F0;
   transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.dropdown li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #00A0F0;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
.menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    left: 0;   
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
}

.dropdown > .col {
  display: block;  
}


.visible {
  display: block;
}

.col {  
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 99;
}

.col > ul {

}
.col > ul > li {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.sub-col > ul > li {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.sub-sub-col > ul > li {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.sub-sub-sub-col > ul > li {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.col> ul > li:last-child { 
}



.sub-col {
  position: absolute;
  left: 510px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  
  
}

.sub-sub-col {
  position: absolute;
  left: 510px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;

}
.sub-sub-sub-col {
  position: absolute;
  left: 510px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.active .col {
  display: block;
}
.col .active .sub-col{
  display: block;
}

.col .sub-col .active .sub-sub-col {
  display: block;
}
 .col .sub-col .sub-sub-col .active .sub-sub-sub-col{
  display: block;
}

.col,.sub-col,.sub-sub-col,.sub-sub-sub-col {
   
}

.iva-children-indenter {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 30%;
    margin-top: 7px;
    color: #00A0F0;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.iva-children-indenter-2{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 30%;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    color: #00A0F0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a2e210f715.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mada:400,500,600" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu-item-1</a>   
          
          <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="col">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item: 1.1</a></li>
                <li class="deeper-nav"><a href="#">Menu-item: 1.2<span class="iva-children-indenter"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
                    <div class="sub-col">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Menuitem1.2.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menuitem1.2.2<span class="iva-children-indenter-2"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                            <div class="sub-sub-col">
                              <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Menuitem1.2.2.1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menuitem1.2.2.2<span class="iva-children-indenter-2"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                                  <div class="sub-sub-sub-col">
                                    <ul>
                                      <li><a href="#">menuitem1.2.2.2.1</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">menuitem1.2.2.2.2</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </div>
                                  </a></li>
                               </ul>
                            </div><!--sub-sub-col-->
                          </a></li>   
                        </ul>
                      </div><!--sub-col-->
                  </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item-1.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item-1.4</a></li>
               </ul>
              </div>  <!--col-->  
             </div><!--dropdown-->
            </li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu-item-2</a>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="col">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item: 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item: 2.2 <span class="iva-children-indenter-2"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>       
                  <div class="sub-col">
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Menuitem2.2.1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">menuitem2.2.2<span class="iva-children-indenter-2"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                        <div class="sub-sub-col">
                          <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Menuitem2.2.2.1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menuitem2.2.2.2
                              <!--<div class="sub-sub-sub-col">
                                <ul>
                                  <li><a href="#">menuitem1.2.2.2.1</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">menuitem1.2.2.2.2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                              </div>-->
                              </a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div><!--sub-sub-col-->
                        </a></li>   
                    </ul>
                  </div><!--sub-col-->
                  </a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>  <!--col-->  
           </div><!--dropdown-->
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#"><a href="#">Menu-item-3</a></a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#"><a href="#">Menu-item-4</a></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--inner-->
</div><!--container-->
```

[Codepen Link Here](https://codepen.io/mohammednawaz/pen/jLweoJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $('.sub-sub-col > ul > li').click(function() {
     if(!$(this).find('.sub-sub-sub-col').length){
      return false;
     }
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks'); //continue your code
});
```

Or:

```
 if(!$(this).children('.sub-sub-sub-col').length){
  return false;
 }
```

**================================================**

```
//   if click on sub-col
  $('.sub-col > ul > li').on('click', function(){
      if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('.dropdown').animate({
             'left' : '10px'
        })  
      }
  });

   $('.sub-sub-col > ul > li').click(function() {
  // var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
      if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('.dropdown').animate({
             'left' : '10px'
        })   
      }
      else {
        $('.dropdown').animate({
             'left' : '-510px'
        })
      }
  // $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/bharathkumar_sriram/pen/vJZqEW?editors=1010 in this click on Menu-item1> menu-item 1.2>menu-item1.2.2>menu-item1.2.2.2  Now click on Menu-item1 two times sub-menu is not opening what might be the problem?

Comment: Menu is opening but it remains in left

Comment: @BharathKumar I wrote above. Why you use .sub-sub-col > ul > li and etc? This is strict binding. You may use one class for all parents and another for dropdown